# Talk to Exchange 2003 from Java

Tags: java, .net, exchange-server

What choices might I have for talking to an Exchange 2003 server from a Java application?  I've heard a few references to projects that offer some .NET services to Java.  I think I've also heard something about Exchange 2007 exposing web services, but I'm not sure if that's available in 2003.

Has anyone done this?  Any suggestions?

Edit: by "talk to" I don't mean just getting messages, which I could do via IMAP...I mean accessing things that are more Exchange-specific, like contacts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use WebDAV to access Exchange Server 2003:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa486282(EXCHG.65).aspx

This MSDN article demonstates how to manipulate the contacts using WebDAV:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296126
(Example code is written in VB, but it should give you an idea on how to do it.)

Comment: Yes - WebDAV is a network protocol, so as long as you can get the WebDAV message on the wire from the Java app, it will deliver the same results as the VB app.

Answer (score 4):

For Exchange 2003, you can use WebDav.  Apache had an older Slide library to help with this, but you really don't need it.  You can just use the HttpClient from Apache Commons. [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/07/21/connecting-java-to-exchange-over-webdav-with-apache-httpclient.aspx).

If you are doing Exchange 2007, then use EWS, via web services. Easier, richer.   [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/07/29/connecting-to-exchange-using-jax-ws-part-1.aspx).